# Use sklearn DBSCAN model to classify new entries

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have a huge "dynamic" dataset and I'm trying to find interesting clusters on it.

After running a lot of different unsupervised clustering algorithms I have found a configuration of [DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) which gives coherent results.

I would like to extrapolate the model that `DBSCAN` creates according to my test data to apply it to other datasets, but without re-running the algorithm. I cannot run the algorithm over the whole dataset cause it would run out of memory, and the model might not make sense to me at a different time as the data is dynamic.

Using **sklearn**, I have found that other clustering algorithms - like [MiniBatchKMeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans) - have a `predict` method, but `DBSCAN` does not.

I understand that for `MiniBatchKMeans` the centroids uniquely define the model. But such a thing might not exist for `DBSCAN`.

So my **question** is: What is the proper way to extrapolate the `DBSCAN` model? should I train a supervised learning algorithm using the output that `DBSCAN` gave on my test dataset? or is there something intrinsically belonging to `DBSCAN` model that can be used to classify new data without re-running the algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Train a classificator based on your model.

DBSCAN is not easy to adapt to new objects, because you would need to eventually adjust minPts. Adding points to DBSCAN can cause clusters to *merge*, which you probably do not want to happen.

If you consider the clusters found by DBSCAN to be useful, train a classifier to put new instances into the same classes. You now want to perform classification, not rediscover structure.

Answer (score 4):

DBSCAN and other 'unsupervised' clustering methods can be used to automatically propagate labels used by classifiers (a 'supervised' machine learning task) in what as known as 'semi-supervised' machine learning. I'll break down the general steps for doing this and cite a series of semi-supervised papers that motivated this approach.

1. By some means, label a small portion of your data.
2. Use DBSCAN or other clustering method (e.g. k-nearest neighbors) to cluster your labeled and unlabeled data.
3. For each cluster, determine the most common label (if any) for members of the cluster. Re-label all members in the cluster to that label. This effectively increased the number of labeled training data.
4. Train a supervised classifier using the dataset from step 3.

The following papers propose some extensions to this general process to improve classification performance. As a note, all of the following papers have found that k-means is a consistent, efficient, and effective clustering method for semi-supervised learning compared to about a dozen other clustering methods. They then use k-nearest neighbors with a large K value for classification. One paper that specifically covered DBSCAN based clustering is:
- Erman, J., & Arlitt, M. (2006). Traffic classification using clustering algorithms. In Proceedings of the 2006 SIGCOMM workshop on Mining network data (pp. 281–286). https://doi.org/http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1162678.1162679

*NOTE: These papers are listed in chronological order and build upon each other. The 2016 Glennan paper is what you should read if you only want to see the most successful/advanced iteration.*

- Erman, J., & Arlitt, M. (2006). Traffic classification using clustering algorithms. In Proceedings of the 2006 SIGCOMM workshop on Mining network data (pp. 281–286). https://doi.org/http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1162678.1162679
- Wang, Y., Xiang, Y., Zhang, J., & Yu, S. (2011). A novel semi-supervised approach for network traffic clustering. In 5th International Conference on Network and System Security (NSS) (pp. 169–175). Milan, Italy: IEEE. https://doi.org/10.1109/ICNSS.2011.6059997
- Zhang, J., Chen, C., Xiang, Y., & Zhou, W. (2012). Semi-supervised and compound classification of network traffic. In Proceedings - 32nd IEEE International Conference on Distributed Computing Systems Workshops, ICDCSW 2012 (pp. 617–621). https://doi.org/10.1109/ICDCSW.2012.12
- Glennan, T., Leckie, C., & Erfani, S. M. (2016). Improved Classification of Known and Unknown Network Traffic Flows Using Semi-supervised Machine Learning. In J. K. Liu & R. Steinfeld (Eds.), Information Security and Privacy: 21st Australasian Conference (Vol. 2, pp. 493–501). Melbourne: Springer International Publishing. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-40367-0_33