# Classification Using DBSCAN w/ Test-Train Split

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan

The question proposed reads as follows: Use scikit-learn to split the data into a training and test set. Classify the data as either cat or dog using DBSCAN.

I am trying to figure out how to go about using DBSCAN to fit a model using training data and then predict the labels of a testing set. I am well aware that DBSCAN is meant for clustering and not prediction. I have also looked at [Use sklearn DBSCAN model to classify new entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625550/use-sklearn-dbscan-model-to-classify-new-entries) as well as numerous other threads.  DBSCAN only comes with fit and fit_predict functions, which don't seem relatively useful when trying to fit the model using the training data and then test the model using the testing data.

Is the question worded poorly or am I missing something? I have looked at the scikit-learn documentation as well as looked for examples, but have not had any luck.

```py
# Split the samples into two subsets, use one for training and the other for testing
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

# Instantiate the learning model
dbscan = DBSCAN()

# Fit the model
dbscan.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict the response

# Confusion matrix and quantitative metrics
print("The confusion matrix is: " + np.str(confusion_matrix(y_test, dbscan_pred)))
print("The accuracy score is: " + np.str(accuracy_score(y_test, dbscan_pred)))
```

Comment: Effectively duplicate of [Use sklearn DBSCAN model to classify new entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625550/use-sklearn-dbscan-model-to-classify-new-entries) because a training/test split only makes sense if you can predict learned labels on new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoever gave you that assignment has no clue...

DBSCAN will *never* predict "cat" or "dog". It just can't.

Because it is an unsupervised algorithm, it doesn't use training labels. **`y_train` is ignored (see the parameter documentation), and it is stupid that sklearn will allow you to pass it at all!** It will output sets of points that are clusters. Many tools will enumerate these sets as 1, 2, ... But it won't name a set "dogs".

Furthermore it can't predict on new data either - which you need for predicting on "test" data. So it can't work with a train-test split, but that does not really matter because it does not use labels anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer in the question you linked is a pretty good one for you, too: [you want to perform classification, not discover structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29626909/13604) (which is what clustering does).

DBSCAN, as implemented in scikit-learn, is a transductive algorithm, meaning you can't do predictions on *new* data. There's an [old discussion from 2012 on the scikit-learn repository](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/901) about this.

Suffice to say, when you're using a clustering algorithm, the concept of train/test splits is less defined. Cross-validation usually involves a different metric; for example, in K-means, the cross-validation is often over the hyperparameter `k`, rather than mutually exclusive subsets of the data, and the metric that is optimized is the intra-vs-inter cluster variance, rather than F1 accuracy.

Bottom line: trying to perform classification using a clustering technique is effectively square-peg-round-hole. You can jam it through if you really want to, but it'd be considerably easier to just use an off-the-shelf classifier.

Comment: So the question is just horribly worded because DBSCAN isn't meant for classification purposes. One can use the labels DBSCAN comes up with for a classification algorithm, but shouldn't be using or trying to use the model to do the classification, yes?

Comment: @user3727648 You can essentially kludge together an F1 score by figuring out what ground truth label each DBSCAN prediction "maps" to. This is fraught with issues, not the least of which is if DBSCAN manages to split a class in half, then the "mapping" between prediction and ground-truth is ambiguous. But even if it does work, you have a transductive model that isn't useful for new data, so yeah there's no real train-test cross-validation possible.

Comment: I decided to use fit_predict() on the entire set of data, which just clusters everything into a single cluster (label). Comparing that to the actual labels seems meaningless.